# No taskbar and icons 13.04

Tags: nvidia, windows-7, icons, taskbar

So I've been playing around the past few days with Ubuntu (still new to it), and then I wanted to upgrade my nvidia drivers to the latest beta version, I messed up horribly ad now the taskbar and the icons don't show + the resolution is in 1280x720 instead of 1920x1080 and I have no internet access in Ubuntu. Oh and I'm dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 7

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have u checked your resolution is correct and also make sure you revert back any changes you made to the system maybe the driver has conflicted with unity causing the incorrect display

Comment: I can't change the resolution since I can't open it, right-click also doesn't work. How can I revert the changes?